# Type Error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' when Sending a JWT to server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this problem when sending JWT to the server the servers sees the JWT, yet the front-end js sends this error and refuse to continue any idea what I am doing wrong thanks.

singup.js:127 TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)'

```js
if (e.target.closest('.my-form2')) {
    let x = document.cookie;
    let cookie = x.split('=')
    let JWTs = cookie[1]
    let content = JSON.stringify({ Authentication: `Bearer ${JWTs}` })

    return fetch('/app', {
      method: 'GET',
      //mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: content
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
        console.log(user.location);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }).catch(err => {
        if (err === "server") return
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`headers` should be an object, but it's currently a string because you do `` let content = JSON.stringify({ Authentication: `Bearer ${JWTs}` }) ``. Remove `JSON.stringify`:

`` let content = { Authentication: `Bearer ${JWTs}` }; ``

Comment: Sounds like the server returned a response that is not JSON.

Comment: I did it , but SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: not working for some reason my content look like following now {Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZC…zA3fQ.AoqBVR65FFUJvwLL942OTcvDoqZrRxfr3cYvQFt1Y0c"}

Comment: What if you `console.log(response.text())` before returning `response.json()`?